# Rails background jobs in Dockerized sidekiq duplicates schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, sidekiq, whenever

I use Rails+Sidekiq with whenever gem.
Both app and sidekiq are separate docker containers running via docker-compose.

```
services:
 app:
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ...

 sidekiq:
  build:
  ...
```

There is one folder app for both services (app and sidekiq). And my problem is that all tasks in **schedule.rb** run two times (one for app container and another for sidekiq container)

Is there is method to check if it is a sidekiq container not to start scheduled jobs?

(sidekiq starts by command: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -L /my-app/log/sidekiq_production.log`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs don't get created magically from the schedule.rb file. They are only created when you run

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

or similar. Remove this command from your script that runs in the Sidekiq container.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it. I had special script in intializers that did crontab update. Moved it to entrypoint script only for app container